# How does git squash deal with deleted files?

Tags: git

Say I added file A as a commit then decided to delete file A. Instead of using git --amend, I instead create another commit that removes file A, I know this is bad practice. However, if I want to merge my branch using git merge --squash. How does git squash deal with the two commits? Does it keep some information of file A in the squashed commit or file A will not show up at all in the commit.

Another way to think of it is if file A was a 1GB file. I don't want my git to store a 1GB file in its history when I do delete file A and squashed merged the branch.

Comment: [bk2204's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59870011/1256452) is right and answers the question you asked, about use of `git merge --squash` (which has to use the merge engine). There's another way to do this *before* merging, with `git reset --soft`, and that just uses the final snapshot. Don't worry if this doesn't make sense right now, I'm mostly attaching this comment for future readers who might be using that approach.

Answer (score 12):

When you perform a squash merge, Git takes all the changes from the starting commit through the end commit and produces one commit that is equivalent.  So if within the commits that you've squashed you've added and removed a file, then the net result is that no file existed, and Git will not record anything about that file in the resulting commit.

The objects referenced by those commits may still exist in your repository for some time even if they're not in the history of your branch, since they can be referenced by the reflog (which keeps a history of your branches), but eventually they'll be deleted if they aren't referenced by any branch, tag, or other ref.

Comment: ... and the obsolete objects referenced by the squashed-out commits are not linked in any of your refs, so they don't get pushed to an upstream repo with `git push`.